# How to add a Mac to Windows Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, mac

I've gone into the Directory Utility on the mac, clicked on the services tab, entered the Active Directory Domain and Computer ID, clicked the Bind button and it showed a little status label which flickered through 5 of 5 steps and then said "An unknown error occurred".

If I ignore the error and just click the OK button further down the screen and make sure the Active Directory service is ticked in the list of services, then go to the Directory Servers tab and try to add an Active Directory by entering my ad domain, computer id, admin username and password I get an error "Unable to add the domain. An unexpected error of type -14090 (eDSAuthFailed) occurred."

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out I had followed all the steps correctly except that I was entering my machine local admin username and password when trying to do the bind. You eeeediot stimpy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either the credentials you provided were incorrect to join the computer to the domain or the AD server is not set up to allow that machine to join it.

Assuming your credentials are correct, and you see nothing else preventing that computer from joining the domain, try to follow this guide over again from scratch:

`Expired link removed`

Comment: I had a similar issue and by following the guide realised that the time was out ( it was set to the old time server) and over 3 minutes out is too much for kerberos.